# i am trying to make a loop but its not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, loops

I am Making a loop so that it plot the graph of every element in this data.
but showing an error
[image]

i am using this loop

```
 import seaborn as sns
 for i in dn:
     sns.distplot(dn[i])
     plt.show()
```

dn look like this
[image]

Comment: Please explain your code and error.

Comment: @Xilpex i dont know the error  and i already show the error in the pic  given above  and this is some looping problem

Comment: What does dn look like? Can you add a reproducible example?

Comment: hi @arabinelli   i had upload the pic of my dn

Answer (score 0):

You can use the loop

```
 for i in dn:
     sns.distplot(i)
     plt.show()
```

It will iterate over all items

Comment: no its not working    i is showing only name of feature its a string it dont contain data

Comment: can you upload the dn list?